# Hierarchical todo list for Linux

Tags: linux, todo

I'm looking for a self-hosted TODO list, with hierarchy and a notes field for each task. Pretty simple, I think. The closest ones I found were MyLifeOrganized (Windows only and a bit overkill)...

[image: MyLifeOrganized]

...and [Quire](https://quire.io/) (hosted in the cloud).

[image: Quire]

Couldn't find anything for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[CherryTree 0.37.6](https://www.giuspen.com) is a **Hierarchical Note Taking Application**, featuring Rich Text and Syntax Highlighting. Not really a TODO manager, but so versatile I could perhaps be used as.

Answer (score 1):

TaskCoach (https://www.taskcoach.org/) is a hierarchical task manager that runs on Linux as well as Windows and MacOS.  It allows you to display the task list in several different ways (e.g., as a flat list as well as a hierarchy), and supports notes, priorities, and categories.

Comment: Thanks for he recommendation. I [wasn't able to install TaskCoach on Ubuntu](https://sourceforge.net/p/taskcoach/bugs/1712/).